# How to add a hyperlink to an outputted value to link it its source

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following formula which outputs a value from another sheet. This is functioning just as it should.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$164,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

The formula and functions above are new to me, so I am not entirely sure how to add a link.

The formula above is looping through the data I have to check if the row has $F$4 in it, so adding the hyperlink is a bit more complex.

How can I add a hyperlink to the output, so that it will hyperlink to where the source cell?

I have tried the following. Upon initial completion of the formula and entering "Ctrl+Shift+Enter", a file window opens like I am trying to open a new file. However, when I click on the cell after, it does nothing. I have Excel 2016

```
=HYPERLINK("#Planner!B"  &  SMALL(IF($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330,ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS(Sheet1!$A$1:A1))+10,  IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$164,
SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),""))
```

Main sheet

[image]

Planner Sheet

[image]

Comment: If you carve out the first half of your equation, do you get a cell reference? It doesn't seem like what you have would do that. I think you need `index()` in there somewhere.

Comment: @gns100 Which part specifically?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The hyperlink formula requires a cell reference or URL, so is that part of your really a cell reference? Specifically this part`="#Planner!B"  &  SMALL(IF($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330,ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS(Sheet1!$A$1:A1))+10`

Comment: @gns100 When I do that the referred cell appears. This is exactly what populated.... `#Planner!B13`

Comment: I had to check, it looks like you need the file name in there too. So put in `[file name]` in front of the `#` symbol. Make sure to use the brackets.

Comment: @gns100 Like this? `"[file name]#Planner!B"  &  SMALL`? If so, this is what populated....`[file name]#Planner!B13`

Comment: yes now replace `file name` with the actual file name of your workbook (probably don't need the extension).

Comment: @gns100 Thanks for all the help. I entered in "Launch Playbook" which is the name of the workbook. Then I entered the .xls after it. Netiher worked. Then I copied the entire filename including all the folder structure. This file is stored on a share point. Her eis the example of what I entered........https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/OHAMarketingTeam/Shared%20Documents/Launch%20Playbook/Launch%20Playbook.xlsm?web=1

Comment: This is the example from excel help function `=HYPERLINK("[http://example.microsoft.com/report/budget report.xlsx]'First Quarter'!DeptTotal")`. I'm guessing your file name conforms to the example. So, it looks like you need the single quotations around the tab name, also does your tab name include the `#`? If not you'll need to get rid of that.

Comment: @gns100 Alright, so I tried the new method and changed my formula back to whole to see if it works. The cell ref is outputting again correctly but when I click on the cell nothing happens. Here's what I have. `=HYPERLINK("[https://example.sharepoint.com/Launch%20Playbook/Launch%20Playbook.xlsm?web=1]'Planner'!B"  &  SMALL(IF($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330,ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS(Sheet1!$A$1:A1))+10,  IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$164, SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),""))`

Comment: Yes, getting `HYPERLINK` to work is a PITA. But, it is so satisfying when it does work. The only thing I see now (but don't know if it is the last issue) is that the example shows spaces while your link uses the `%20` representation for space.  Otherwise, see if you can get a hardcoded hyperlink to work first before using the formula.

Comment: @gns100 Good point on seeing if the hardcode one works first. I just tried a very simple example `=HYPERLINK(Planner!B13,"A1")`.  I keep getting an error prompt that says: `Unable to open "link". The internet site reports that the item you requested could not be found. (HTTP/1.0 404)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=HYPERLINK("#"  &  ADDRESS(MATCH(Planner!$F$4,Planner!$A$11:$A$164,0)+10,1,,,"Planner"),  IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$164,SMALL(IF((Planner!$F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),""))
```

Perhaps I greatly misunderstand, but nothing I see in the question or comments seems to contradict the first line in the question that says the sheet is in the same spreadsheet. So paths and filenames seem unnecessary.

So, instead of thinking of generating the value and then hyperlinking it, think in terms of generating an address for the hyperlink function to act upon achieving the hyperlinking action, and use `HYPERLINK`'s second parameter, that of a "friendly name" to display in the cell for the formula you give that generates the value.

So your value will display in the cell, but clicking on it will activate the hyperlink to go to the generated address.

Speaking of which, I suppose there is some reason for the curious way you generate the lookup. I suppose that because you use a variety of ranges in the formula that differ from each other in that they use different, and different size, sets of rows where a lookup like `XLOOKUP` would have the ranges rather more in lockstep. I guess. Not asking. But because the given formula is essentially a simple lookup, for the demonstration of the solution, I used a simple `MATCH` of F4 on the column A range to generate the row number (the result plus the 10 rows not included before the range starts) and a simple 1 for the column in the `ADDRESS` function. This will actually work for your situation no matter the reason for your unique lookup mechanism, as the address you want is the simple `MATCH` I did anyway.

The only complication in the `ADDRESS` function is that the place you want the hyperlink to take you is on sheet `Planner` so you must specify that as `ADDRESS`'s final parameter.

To recap, `HYPERLINK` will use the `ADDRESS` and `MATCH` mechanism to create the address to link to. It will also generate a "friendly name" for display in the cell that just happens to be the value your lookup finds. So you display the value you wish to display, but have a working hyperlink to take you to the source.

**NOTE:**  Sadly, you cannot place a similar mechanism in the cells you go to thinking to then click those hyperlinks to return to the places you started. Excel will see it as an infinite loop and quit, giving you an error. But you can use this technique in a cell next to this one's target (and therefore easy to click after looking at the target) which can return you. The fact that the cell right next to this one's target may have nothing at all to do with the situation doesn't matter. It is conveniently close to the user's visual attention center (the target of this hyperlink) so no aggravation for him to click the cell next to it to return to his starting place.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the answer. This does not appear to be doing the trick. The output now shows `#N/A` and the link doesn't work.